# Finding the order of an element in a group ( a given $a^3$, etc.)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Supposing $a$ is a group element, what are possible values of $|a|$ if:

$1.\;\;|a^3| = 20$

$2.\;\;|a^6| = 20$

$3.\;\;|a^6| = 19$

For the first one I got $60$, the second I got $120$ and the third I got $114$. I know that there should be more, I'm just not seeing how to get to them.

Comment: Which group does $a$ dwell in?

Comment: doesn't matter.

Comment: a does not dwell within a specific group. I just know that a^3 and a^6 are elements of <a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that $\langle a^k \rangle = \langle a^{\mathrm{gcd}(k,n)} \rangle$ if $|a|=n$. This then means that if $|a|=n$, $|a^k|=|a^{\mathrm{gcd}(k,n)}|=\dfrac{n}{\mathrm{gcd}(k,n)}$.

So what about #1: $|a^3|=20$? We have $\dfrac{n}{\mathrm{gcd}(3,n)}=20$ that is $20\cdot \mathrm{gcd}(3,n) = n$. Well, the only divisors of $3$ are 1 and itself, so $\mathrm{gcd}(3,n)$ is either 1 or 3. Thus $|a|=n=20 \cdot 1 = 20$ or $20 \cdot 3 = 60$.

I hope this helps get you started!

**Edit:** Both *are* in fact possible. For example, if $a=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$, then $3a=3$ (written additively since $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ is a group under addition) has order $20$. So $|a|=60$ but $|3a|=20$.

On the other hand, if $a=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$, then $3a=3$ has order $20$ as well. That is: $|a|=|3a|=20$ (this is because 20 and 3 are relatively prime).

Comment: How would one rule out possible values? Because I don't believe 20 works as a order of a for the first one.

Comment: For instance I got n = 20, 40, 60, 120 for 2 but I don't know if all of them are correct. Is there any method to test if they work?

Comment: You don't have enough information to *exactly* pin down the order of $a$ given information about the order of $a^3$. That's just the way it is!

Comment: Oh all right- thank you very much for the insight!

Comment: I got n = 20, 40, 60 and 120 for 2 and n = 19, 38, 57 and 114 for 3 for any future visitors to the page.